# Selecting text in CKEditor5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to replicate a functionality provided by a plugin in CKEditor 4 but not present in CKEditor 5. The functionality is what the [Element Path plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/elementspath) offered.

If you check out the link, I have implemented the part where I can display a list of HTML element names in the current cursor position at the bottom of the editor interface. However, I am not getting anywhere trying to achieve the second part of the functionality which is "Clicking an element name on the Elements Path selects the element in the editor content".

Here is my code:

```js
import { Plugin } from 'ckeditor5/src/core';

export default class ElementPathEditing extends Plugin {

  init() {
    const editor = this.editor;

    // Create a UI element to display the path
    editor.once('ready', () => {
      const pathElement = document.createElement('div');
      pathElement.classList.add('path-display');
      pathElement.textContent = 'body';

      // Find the container for the CKEditor UI toolbar and append your custom element to it
      const uiContainer = editor.ui.view.editable.element.parentNode;
      uiContainer.appendChild(pathElement);

      editor.editing.view.document.on('selectionChange', () => {
        const selection = editor.editing.view.document.selection;
        const anchor = selection.getFirstPosition();

        if (anchor) {
          let path = [];
          let currentElement = anchor.parent;

          // Traverse up the view hierarchy and collect element names.
          while (currentElement) {
            path.unshift(currentElement.name);
            currentElement = currentElement.parent;
          }

          if (path.length > 0 && path[0] === 'div') {
            path[0] = 'body';
          }
          pathElement.innerHTML = path
            .map((item) => {
              if (item !== undefined) { // Check if it's an element
                const el = document.createElement('a');
                el.classList.add('path-segment');

                el.textContent = item;
                el.href = `javascript:void('${item}')`;
                return el.outerHTML;
              }
              return '';
            })
            .join(' ');

          pathElement.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(elem => {
            elem.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
              // not sure what to add here

            })
          })

        }
      });
    });
  }

}
```

As you see, inside the click eventListener towards the bottom of this code is where I am thinking about handling the click on the elements and then selecting the corresponding element in the editor. Note that I want to actually **select** the text so that it can be copied, etc.. **not** just highlight it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.